# Console escrever 2 strings da lista

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Criei uma lista no qual adicionei 2 strings:

```
var lista = new List<string> {cliente.Nome, cliente.Sobrenome};
```

E no final eu queria que mostrasse assim:

```
Console.WriteLine(lista[0]);
```

Mas mostra só o nome, por que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque só está mandando imprimir o primeiro elemento, se quer imprimir os dois elementos precisa mandar fazer isto explicitamente. Assim:

```
WriteLine(${lista[0] - lista[1]});
```

Note que ele não está escrevendo o nome, está escrevendo o elemento 0 do *array*. Você sabe que é um nome, mas ele não sabe, pra ele é apenas uma *string* qualquer.

Só é um pouco estranho querer colocar idade como uma `string`. Provavelmente toda esta ideia está errada, não parece que precisa de uma lista aí, mas não posso afirmar sem um contexto maior.

Isto também é bem esquisito, adicionar uma lista nela mesma?

```
lista.AddRange(lista);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/AddRange.cs).

Alguma coisa me diz que deve ter vários outros erros no código.